# Reloading page custom fetched data

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, tabs

Basically I'm trying to load a tab with the following `unique_id` data from a button. The issue is I want the tab to load with the corresponding variable without reloading the page. I've looked on here for solutions regarding ajax URL rewrite but nothing is working. I dont care about adding more files here and there I just need a solution to this minor problem. Thanks

```php
<a href="?user_id='. $row['unique_id'] .'">
... blah .. stuff.. etc
</a>
```

Comment: so you want a link that queries something on the back-end, which then returns html, which will then appear in a tab - without reloading the page, right? Pretty much a straight-up `ajax` request?

Comment: @Kinglish Yes, the code above is already being handled by an ajax event however, when its comes to loading the unique id tab, it only works when the browser is reloaded

Comment: Exactly what do you need? The `href` above to change to contain the unique_id in the query string? I dont' understand this statement:  _when its comes to loading the unique id tab, it only works when the browser is reloaded_

Comment: @Kinglish I want the user to hit a button with the link as stated above to load data on a sub tab without reloading the page. I can only achieve this if the page reloads

Comment: Where does the unique_id come from? Or, actually back to an earlier question. Do you just need to know how to trigger an ajax event which will write content into a tab?

Comment: @Kinglish Yes please regarding the ajax event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax loading into a tab in 2 flavors, vanilla and jquery

```js
function loadTabOG() {
  let url = 'someURLThatWillReturnHTML.php';
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(html => {
      document.getElementById('tab-2').innerHTML += html
    })


  // the snippet won't allow us to do an ajax request, so we'll simulate the response here.
  document.getElementById('tab-2').innerHTML += "<p>Here is some new html from regular javascript</p>";
}


function loadTabJQ() {
  let url = 'someURLThatWillReturnHTML.php';
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
  }).done(function(html) {
    $('#tab-2').append(html)
  });

  // the snippet won't allow us to do an ajax request, so we'll simulate the response here.
  $('#tab-2').append("<p>Here is some new html from jquery</p>")
}
```

```css
.tab {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tab' id='tab-1'>
  <h3>Tab 1</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='loadTabOG()'>Load tab 2 using regular javascript</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='loadTabJQ()'>Load tab 2 using jquery</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class='tab' id='tab-2'>
  <h3>Tab 2</h3>
  <div>
```